# Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer

Tags: typescript

How i can set correct type for `config` and don't lose keys for generic below?

Types:

```
type ActionCreatorType = (...args: any[]) => any;
type ActionConfig = [ActionCreatorType, ActionCreatorType]

type ActionsMapConfigType = Record<string, ActionConfig>
type ActionMapType<T extends ActionsMapConfigType> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ActionCreator<T[K][0], T[K][1]>
}

type ActionType<P extends ActionCreatorType, M extends ActionCreatorType> = {
  type: string,
  payload: P,
  meta: M,
}

type ConcatArguments<P extends ActionCreatorType, M extends ActionCreatorType> = Parameters<P> & Parameters<M>;
type ActionCreator<P extends ActionCreatorType, M extends ActionCreatorType> = (...args: ConcatArguments<P, M>) => ActionType<P, M>
```

utils:

```
export const createActions = <T extends ActionsMapConfigType>(prefix: string, actionsMap: ActionsMapConfigType): ActionMapType<T> => {
  const result: Partial<ActionMapType<T>> = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(actionsMap)) {
    result[key as keyof ActionMapType<T>] = (...args: any[]) => ({
      type: `${prefix}_${key}`,
      payload: value[0](...args),
      meta: Object.assign({}, ...value[1](...args)),
    })
  }
  return result as ActionMapType<T>;
};
```

using

```
const config = {
  test: [
    (a: number) => ({}),
    (a: number, b: string) => ({}),
  ]
}

const action = createActions<typeof config>('form', config);
```

`createActions<typeof config>('form', config)` - contain error "Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the type widening of the `config` object. When you hover over `config`, you will see that the type is

```
const config: {
    test: ((a: number, b: string) => {})[];
}
```

instead of

```
const config: {
    test: [
      (a: number) => {}, 
      (a: number, b: string) => {}
    ]
}
```

So TypeScript automatically widened the type of `config` to contain an array instead of a tuple of length `2`. The information about the amount of elements inside the array was lost which logically leads to the error message.

> Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.

---

What can we do to fix this?

We could use the `as const` assetions when declaring `config`.

```
const config = {
  test: [
    (a: number) => ({}),
    (a: number, b: string) => ({}),
  ] as const
}
```

This will force TypeScript to use the narrowest type. In this case a tuple.

It marks the tuple as `readonly` though so we have to modify `ActionConfig` to accept `readonly` tuples.

```
type ActionConfig = readonly [ActionCreatorType, ActionCreatorType]
```

The error is now gone.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=68&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYGEBOECGxmYAq40AvFABQB0NOmA5gM4BcUOqIA2gLoCUUpAHxsOAbgBQoSLAQoMaAGaJ6AqNhwATNABsQUTvCRosufERIAaGUYzqzxSN3GSS1uYwCyOMOkXKHZFAAShBwBBoAPIzAmIio9FaGcr6oSvSCLtJJaF5gARGEUBAAHsAQqBqMbmie3ilpAcLkAN7iUPoA0lBxUADWECDIClCE3KzZtqYEBZwd3JwADNxWhLPzAIzcGQC%20zlLQE-kACkWl5ZXVk3gEAVYep2UVVRMm1%20aQTVCt7fus0bHxCxtKBgHAgbTITSsI5A9oAWwgwBwrA8QN2mWgKTgeBgDAArgjUMBGBETiVHhcXnYbpYoPdyednrJjNT3hBPkc6DgEWVMCSjsIAGRQTmYbmIiB8iIeQQSfaXV5mUkPRkK1m3Okqp5qqZsz7UWgMFhQLE4-GE4mku6CfhCS7Ha3OEpgAjAKBhVDRd12CATKrkApaynMz25er%20EiCChgbBKYp-GJxBJsEO1MDjVNhvz0AK8DM2XL5QhNYTfd01N3YRh47TAaF0JA4bQRCaFkgFQSfZrbCTtBQESger2cfogKwANybeIg3CgQygAHkAEYAK1CwCo5UTEEYFBwme8vH4ZfaVZrwBHAzYVVH89b3iLgln5ANVDoTFY7C4fAEwgoJ-aKBfigAADAASZoYwgONtgAfQg0dthA2FAPaUFwUhDRWEnbRp0WbhX3fRheBQ1CeWRRdV3XN9GEYZRUH-bYrBoKgcLwzZCKNI9SKgbZeGBXZT0RPFMFQNQd3Pa9LjbSAOwkHtnHEIc3Q9NJVDLMpolYThgXaPdWFQAkl0lW0-27EjdMoCjDLhYzMCsJcEwBehTMocyUNnHAqmU8RtigZxlJTGxVDgH0-QoAByftMDhCKrFU5ReFEIA)

---

You can also directly pass the object literal to the `createActions` function.

```
const action = createActions('form', {
  test: [
    (a: number) => ({}),
    (a: number, b: string) => ({}),
  ]
});
```

The type will be narrowed down correctly here too.

---

To help TypeScript automatically infer the type of `T`, you need to also change the defintion of `createActions`.

```
export const createActions = <T extends ActionsMapConfigType>(prefix: string, actionsMap: T): ActionMapType<T> => {
  /* ... */
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYGEBOECGxmYAq40AvFABQB0NOmA5gM4BcUOqIA2gLoCUUpAHxsOAbgBQoSLAQoMaAGaJ6AqNhwATNABsQUTvCRosufERIAaGUYzqzxSN3GSS1uYwCyOMOkXKHZFAAShBwBBoAPIzAmIio9FaGcr6oSvSCLtJJaF5gARGEUBAAHsAQqBqMbmie3ilpAcLkAN7iUPoA0lBxUADWECDIClCE3KzZtqYEBZwd3JwADNxWhLPzAIzcGQC%20zlLQE-kACkWl5ZXVk3gEAVYep2UVVRMm1%20aQTVCt7fus0bHxCxtKBgHAgbTITSsI5A9oAWwgwBwrA8QN2mWgKTgeBgDAArgjUMBGBETiVHhcXnYbpYoPdyednrJjNT3hBPkc6DgEWVMCSjsIAGRQTmYbmIiB8iIeQQSfaXV5mUkPRkK1m3Okqp5qqZsz7UWgMFhQLE4-GE4mku6CfhCS7Ha3OEpgAjAKBhVDRd12CATKrkApaynMz25er%20EiCChgbBKYp-GJxBJsEO1MCsQi8cYh3L5QhNYTfd01N3YRh47TAaF0JA4bQRCa5kgFQSfZrbCTtBQESger2cfogKwANzreIg3CgQygAHkAEYAK1CwCo5UTEEYFBwqdyvH4RfaZYrwAHAzYVUH08b3jzgkn5ANVDoTFY7C4fAEwgoB-aUF%20UAAAwAEmaGMIDjbYAH0QMHbYANhX92lBcFIQ0VhR20cdFm4R9n0YXgEMQnlkVnRdlyfRhGGUVBv22KwaCoDCsM2XCjT3QioG2XhgV2Q9ETxTBUDUDdj3PS4m0gFsJA7ZxxD7N0PTSVQizKaJWE4YF2i3VhUAJOdJVtL92wIzTKBI3S4X0zArDnBMAXoQzKGMhDJxwKp5PEbYoGceSUxsVQ4B9P0KAAcm7TA4RCqxFOUXhRCAA)

Comment: Thank a lot, Tobias. Second way seems interesting, but I don't fully understand syntax. Does generic requires set type before braces, doesn't?

Comment: I am not sure if you mean this, but TypeScript is able to *infer* the generic type based on the object you pass into the function. So you don't alwys have to specify the genric type with `<>`  when you call the function.

Comment: but if i don't specify the generic type with <>, then types dosent work well. Maybe I miss some option?

Comment: hmm. I checked solution with 'as const' and found a problem: in this solution arguments in function `action.test` become just 'never'. I don't understand: why?

Comment: You need to use `T` as the type for `actionsMap`. Otherwise `T` will be automatically inferred to the type `ActionsMapConfigType` as you specified in the constraint. Change the definition to `const createActions = <T extends ActionsMapConfigType>(prefix: string, actionsMap: T): ActionMapType<T>`